# How to move third level li elements up and remove the ul?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, nested-lists

I have a fairly large, three level deep, menu consisting of nested lists like in this example

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">level 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">level 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">level 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For the menu I would like to work with two levels only so I would like to remove the third `ul` and add a class to its (former) children for styling purposes.

Can this be done with jQuery? The result should be looking something like:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li class="third"><a href="#">level 3</a></li>
            <li class="third"><a href="#">level 3</a></li>
            <li class="third"><a href="#">level 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why don't you just generate the markup you wish to have on the server?

Comment: because it's dynamically generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('ul ul ul').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().after($(this).find('li').addClass('third'));
    $(this).remove();
});
```

For every third level UL element, insert all child LI elements after the UL's parent element, then remove the UL itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul ul ul').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().after($(this).find('li').addClass('third'));
  if (!$(this).parents('.exception').length){
   $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: that didn't really work, the ul hierarchy in the .exception doesn't stay intact

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul ul ul li').addClass('third').unwrap().each(function() {
    $(this).parent().after($(this))
})
```